# How to pass response values in Reactive Forms fields?

Tags: angular

I want to fill update form fields to be filled with user existing data on page load.
& I'm calling function for getting user data on my component.ts file like this

```
ngOnInit() {
        const res = this.getUserDetails();
        console.log(res);

        this.updateForm = this.fb.group({
            name: [this.userData.name, Validators.required],
            email: [this.userData.email, [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
            mobile: [this.userData.mobile, Validators.required],
            image: [this.userData.image]
        });
    }
getUserDetails() {
        this.amen.getUserDetails(this.params).subscribe(
            (response) => {
                this.handleResponse(response);
                console.log('Response------------------------', response);
                return response;
            },
            (error) => {
                console.log('Error: ', error);
            }
        );
    }

    handleResponse(response) {
        return this.userData = {
            name: response.responseData.name,
            email: response.responseData.email,
            mobile: response.responseData.mobile,
            image: response.responseData.user_img
        };
    }
```

But it gives me undefined on this line & also data doesn't show on reactive forms

```
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Your not actually returning anything from `getUserDetails` that is why `res` is undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **patchValue**

Try like this:

```
this.amen.getUserDetails(this.params).subscribe(
        (response) => {
            this.updateForm.patchValue(this.handleResponse(response));
            ...
        },
        (error) => {
            console.log('Error: ', error);
        }
    );
```

**Explaination**: In Reactive Forms, if we need to update the input elements on the form from our component class, we use setValue and patchValue

We use patchValue, when we want to change  only a subset of the form element and not all the elements of the form. For  all the elements, use setValue

Comment: Voilla... It works like a charm. Adrita can you please what that line do?

Comment: Setvalue and Patchvalue are used to set input values. setvalue is for all the elements and patch value is for all or some of them

Comment: @AdritaSharma It would be great if you explained your answer rather than just posting code. The answer might actually deserve an up-vote then. Asking for up-votes makes it seem like this is all about rep, and not quality.

Comment: @R.Richards I have explained in the comment. See the comment please

Comment: @R.Richards Is it okay?

Answer (score 0):

this is because you're assigning the value before they're actually fetched from the server.
put

```
const res = this.getUserDetails();
console.log(res);
```

inside you're subscription method and you'll get what you want

Comment: That will create infinite recursive calls.

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: @Lint yes it is buddy.